# Can $\{(1,2,0), (2,0,3)\}$ span subspace $U=\{(r,s,0)\mid r $ and $s$ in $ℝ^n\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is my confusion, $a\times (1,2,0)+0\times (2,0,3)$ can certainly achieve combination but it cannot account for every possible $(r,s,0)$, so how does the question work?

Answer (score 2):

You're right, they can't. In fact, if it could you would have, for a generic $(r,s,0)$,

$$
(s,r,0) = x(1,2,0) + y(2,0,3).
$$
From the third component you get $3y=0$, which means that $(2,0,3)$ cannot be used in the combination. But multiples of $(1,2,0)$ cannot span all possible $(r,s,0)$, with $r,s\in \mathbb{R}$.